# How to burn correctly the FreeBSD 7.2 ISO image in a USB stick

Tags: freebsd, dd, usb-drive, iso

I've found that FreeBSD 7.2 should have kqemu,so I want to try how much good it was. I've written the iso image to my USB stick ( /dev/sdj ) with this command :

```
xzcat 7.2-RELEASE-amd64-dvd1.iso | dd of=/dev/sdi bs=1M

xzcat: 7.2-RELEASE-amd64-dvd1.iso: File format not recognized
```

I have also tried :

```
dd if=7.2-RELEASE-amd64-dvd1.iso of=/dev/sdi
```

Unfortunately it won't burn correctly on the usb stick. Investigating what could have been happened,I've seen this situation on the USB stick :

[image: 1]

It can't boot. Why it burns the iso image like this ? How to fix it ?

Comment: Did you recognise you're writing `sdi` while your device lies at `[…]/sdj`…?  


Are you sure you want `FreeBSD 7` instead of `12` (or `13`), which would be the production release?

Answer (score 1):

Is there any particular reason, you want to use the `*iso` file that is meant for burning to CD/DVD instead of the `*memstick.img` that is meant to be imaged on an USB device?
If not I would suggest to just [follow the instructions](https://docs.freebsd.org/en/books/handbook/bsdinstall/#bsdinstall-usb).

Comment: Did you give a look at this site ?

http://ftp-archive.freebsd.org/pub/FreeBSD-Archive/old-releases/amd64/ISO-IMAGES/7.2/

there aren't img files and memstick files for freebsd 7.2.

Comment: @Marietto Did you look at the release data? Any reason why you want to use such ancient release? In 2009 using USB sticks for installing OSes was almost unheard of.

Comment: @Marietto Ok, now I get it, you would like to try a about 15 years old release, because kvm was first introduced in that release? Is that your reasoning?  Be aware that *some* iso images are prepared in a way that allow them to be imaged to other devices and boot. But generally it does not work if only el torito CD boot is used. You could give the rufus tool a shot, I would never have imagined me recommending a windows tool in a unix/linux forum but that one knows some magic about isolinux and grub booting. Maybe it can do it automatically. It is certainly possible to do that manually somehow.

Comment: [Booting BSD iso wth grub2](https://forums.freebsd.org/threads/boot-freebsd-iso-from-grub2-usb-stick.19701/#post-136640)

Comment: You would like to try a about 15 years old release, because kvm was first introduced in that release? yes. I've installed FreeBSD 7.2 on my old I5 cpu PC using a dvd reader / recorder. I didn't remember that at the time on the config panel there was PPP instead of the detection of a network interface. So,now I'm stuck. I should read how to configure PPP. For sure it can't detect my network interface. It is too new for it. Will be hard to provide a connection to internet to that old version of FreeBSD. Furthermore,I hoped to find some kind of reaction when I wrote "kqemu",but it is not there.

Comment: I would suggest to edit the question and make that clearer. I guess many people misunderstood. If your hardware is old enough and your network device recognized, it shouldn't be too hard to reconfigure it to use DHCP instead of PPP. PPP was used to directly hook up one PC to a DSL modem at that time.